# How to correctly extract the directory from the registry key "ImagePath"?

Tags: c#, .net

I am looking for a particular application install location in registry. Since InstallLocation does not have the value I need, I used ImagePath to get the physical path. However I need the directory and not the full path. What I get is:

```
(string) subkey.GetValue("ImagePath") = 
"\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Some Folder\\Some Other Folder\\TheApplication.exe\""
```

Using

```
Path.GetDirectoryName((string) subkey.GetValue("ImagePath"))
```

throws the following error.

> Illegal characters in path.

Is this due to extra backslashes? I tried removing those with `.Replace(@"\\", "\")` but no luck.

Comment: What does the registry key contain if you look at it as a string, directly? Does it actually contain illegal characters?

Comment: How can we help unless you tell us what `subkey.GetValue("ImagePath")` returns?

Comment: I have updated the post to better present the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the quotes that are causing `Path.GetDirectoryName` to throw the exception.  You can call `Trim` on the returned value to remove the surrounding quotes.

```
string path = ((string)subkey.GetValue("ImagePath")).Trim('"');

string directoryName = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
```